# RSS Feed Blender (NOT concatenate)

Tags: xml, rss

I have found a multitude of sites that can take RSS feeds and combine them BUT they all just take one feed, gets posts, take next feed gets post, etc. and then concatenate them one after another.

Like so:
RSS 1 [0] [1] [2]... Posts + RSS 2 [0] [1] [2]... Posts + RSS 3 [0] [1] [2]... Posts

**The different RSS feeds are never shuffled so articles are evenly not distributed and random in the output feed.**

I want/am looking for a site that will:

```
   1. Get all the input feeds posts
   2. Shuffle posts randomly
   3. Produce RSS feed of shuffled input feeds
```

What I want:
RSS 1 [3] + RSS 2 [0] + RSS 1 [2] .....

Does anyone know of such a thing? I have been search for on hour+ now... and found nothing

Comment: Whtat is the platform you are developing for ?

Comment: Going to be used for a Telescopeapp input feed